# Cuisinart scale gaining weight

Tags: appliances

I have a Cuisinart KML-KO3B precision kitchen scale.  Up to now weighing anything to within a gram or two has been trivial.

Currently when I turn it on, it flashes 8's repeatedly about once per second.  It will do this for 10 to 30 seconds, then tare properly to zero.

Now is the odd bit.

With it still empty, it will gradually increase in weight.  I turned it on and tared it when I started this post, and now it's at 124 grams.  Still empty.

Repeat:
17 flashes. 
Tared.
at 1 minute registering 47 grams.
at 1:30 61 grams
at 2:00 67 grams
at 2:30 73 grams
at 3:00 77 grams

Never heard about this happening.

What is going on?

Can it be fixed?

I have searched for Cuisinart scale KML-KO3B flashing 8's and gotten nothing meaningful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions regarding small appliances are specifically off-topic per the help center.

Answer (score 3):

Consider to replace the batteries and also to clean the contacts within the battery compartment.

Comment: the LCDs run on much less voltage/current than the micro-controller (chip), which is why you can see anything. If the chip is under-powered, you'll often see malarkey on the LCD. If new batteries don't help, you'll have to replace the unit.